# Using rest-assured get value using path method

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to extract value of `s.d.url` from the below JSON.
I am using the below satement as shown using System.out.println
but I dont get the result. How do I do it when the field itself contains "."

JSON

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "H1":{  
         "com.abc.def":{  
            "a_enabled":false,
            "b_config":true
         },
         "c.s.urls":{  
            "s.d.url":"https://url1.com",
            "w.p.url":"https://url2.com",
            "s.c.url":"https://url3.com"
         },
         "com.abc.con":{  
            "e_n":true,
            "a_r":false,
            "c_t":"XYZMB"
         }
      },
      "dCId":"ABCD"
   }
}
```

---

```
ExtractableResponse<Response> spec =  given()
    .request().log().all()
    .expect().statusCode(200)
    .when()
    .get(EndpointsCloudServices.getConfigUrl() + "?" + params)
    .then().log().body()
            .extract();

            //want to get value of s.d.url
            System.out.println("Triage????  " + spec.path("data.H1.c.s.urls.s.d.url"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try for the following, it will return value of `s.d.url` (pay attention for square brackets and single quotes):

`spec.path("data.H1.['c.s.urls'].['s.d.url']")`

or even shorter, if you're sure that `s.d.url` is an unique name across the whole json document:

`spec.path("$.['s.d.url']")`

And next, this is just to illustrate common case of referring field which contains dots in its name by using JSONPath expression - all you need is to wrap the field name in `['` and `']`

Example JSON:

```
{
   "field.name": "value",
   "nested": {
        "field.with.dot": {
             "field.inside": "anotherValue"
        }
    }  
}
```

Example valid JSONPath expressions to access corresponding field values:

```
$['field.name']                                 
$.['field.inside']                            
nested.['field.with.dot'].['field.inside']
```

Hint: you can quickly test your JSONPaths agains your json using tools like [online evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/) or [expression tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)